# SVG (deprecated) vs SVG2 (Candidate Recommendation)

Tags: javascript, svg

**Introduction**

I have been using SVG in my product to draw an image of Office map and then draw individual stations as rectangles on top of it. Also, providing other features like zoom from mouse pointer, drag-drop, auto-refresh. All is done through Javascript only.

**Problem Statement**

I was using SVG for it, along with SVGMatrix, SVGPoint, SVGRect and others. As per documentation on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGMatrix) SVGMatrix is being deprecated and recommended to use DOMMatrix which is still Candidate Recommendation and advised not to use in production (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix).

Which one to stick with as of now?

Also, I couldn't find any Javascript example for SVG2.

Comment: But it is recommended not to use in Production :(

Comment: you don't really have a choice, you'll use whatever the browser gives you.